# Making ajax call on navigating away from page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am working on a site that has multiple links to other sites. What I want is to send an ajax call to report that the user is going away when someone clicks and navigates away from the page. I put an alert on click of the links, which works but for some reason the controller never gets the ping.

Any assistance will be appreciated on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to simply set `click` event handler which will check the `href` attribute of every link before navigating. If it goes to another website, the handler sends AJAX request and then (after server responding) redirects to the page.

```
var redirect = '';
$('a').click(function() {
    if (this.href.host != document.location.host) {
        if (redirect) return false; // means redirect is about to start, clicking other links has no effect
        redirect = this.href;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/away', 
            success: function(){document.location.href = redirect;}
        });
    return false;
});
```

However it can't work properly, if user has opened your page in multiple tabs.

Comment: yeah the call is being registered, but success the redirection doesn't occur

Comment: Then could be a server side error. Maybe the response is returned with code != 200, that's why "success" event doesn't work. Try "done" done instead.

Comment: yeah I was not sending any response at all 0_o

Answer (score 3):

Can't be done.

When you go to navigate away, there is only one event that can catch that, the `onbeforeunload` event, and that is quite limited in what it can do.

Not to mention there are other ways of leaving the page without navigating away:

- Losing network connection
- Closing the browser.
- Losing power.

The only thing you can do is to set up a `heartbeat` kind of thing that pings the server every so many milliseconds and says 'I'm Alive.'

Depending on what you are trying to do, there is usually a better option, however.

Comment: hmm... What I want is to keep the log of links being visited, hence the on redirection from page I want to ping the controller, what i cant comprehend is that if the alert is showing then why wont the ajax call work?

Comment: Because the browser will navigate away before the ajax call has a chance to finish.  It's like hanging up your phone halfway through ordering a pizza.   As far as how to log the link ssomeone follows -- you run those through a link forwarder... `<a href="http://example.com/forward?url=http://example2.com/>example2.com</a>`

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it is working on a slower machine I have, but won't work on other places, forwarder how does that work?

Comment: @Babar You'll have to open a new question for that and say what you are using on the backend.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, but I have to pick another answer as correct, Because it helped solve the issue in my own domain. Thanks none the less.

Answer (score 1):

The only reliable way to do this these days is by *hooking* (i.e. add event listener) your code in so called [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) method from [Beacon API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) on `beforeunload` event (i.e. when user tries to navigate away from page).

The `navigator.sendBeacon()` method asynchronously sends a small amount of data over **HTTP** to a web server. It’s intended to be used for sending analytics data to a web server, and avoids some of the problems with legacy techniques for sending analytics, such as the use of `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
<script>
var URL = 'https://your.domain/your-page.php';
// on 'beforeunload'
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {  
    navigator.sendBeacon(URL);
    // more safely is to wait a bit
    var wait_until = new Date().getTime() + 500;
    while (new Date().getTime() <= wait_until);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    return "This should create a pop-up";
});
```

Comment: But you can't send an ajax request through with `onbeforeunload`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by capturing clicks on all the links on the page (or all the relevant links) and then call `ev.preventDefault()` on it to prevent the browser from navigating directly to that page.

Instead, you can make an AJAX call to your server and when that call returns, you can set `window.location` to the URL the user was trying to navigate to.

Comment: is not this a bit hacky? but it will work, lemme try :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround you could try.

At the loading of the page, use jquery to move all href attributes to tempHref attribute. Then, attach a method to catch the click event.

This way, clicking on the links will not automatically move to the intended destination.
When the click occurs, simply perform the ajax call, and then using javascript, move to the other page.

```
$('a').each(function () {
    var link = $(this);
    link.attr('tempHref', link.attr('href'));
    link.removeAttr('href');
});

$(document).on('click', 'a', function ()
{
    //perform ajax call;
    location.href = $(location).attr('tempHref');
});
```